# Response.Redirect not working on WAP sites in a basic phone model

Tags: c#, asp.net, mobile, nokia

When i click on the Submit Button and on the Button Click i have written a Response.Redirect to a new web page it firstly prompts a message.

**Data you are sending will be redirected to another server. Continue?**

If i say yes it gives an error Response Unknown.

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Default2.aspx",false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Server.Transfer("Default2.aspx");

This function save double trip to the server.

Response.Redirect() sends a redirection header to the client, and the client itself requests the new page.

Server.Transfer() stops rendering the current page and starts rendering another one.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use the "false" only write:

```
Response.Resirect("Default2.aspx");
```